# Java Server Socket failure

Tags: java, sockets

```
while (true) {

    ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
    Socket skt = myServerSocket.accept();

    Handling obj = new Handling();
    obj.handle(skt);

}
```

When i first try this it works fine and accepts the Socket but then when it loops back it says the address is in use. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a new ServerSocket in the loop - you only need to *accept* in the loop:

```
ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
while (true) {
    Socket skt = myServerSocket.accept();
    Handling obj = new Handling();
    obj.handle(skt);
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution, however the reason the OP's code didn't work is that it didn't close() the server socket before creating it again.  This would have worked also but is not good practice.